# Transformation matrix that transforms A into an upper triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

I'm seeking for a transformation matrix $T\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that a given matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ satisfies the following identity:

$A = T^{-1}UT$,

where $U\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is an upper-triangular matrix. How do I obtain such matrices $T$ and $U$? Furthermore, would there be a similar transformation for a block matrix? For example, for a block matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{(m+n)\times(m+n)}$,

$\displaystyle
A \equiv
\left( \begin{array}{c : c}
L & L_Q \\
\hdashline
0 & Q
\end{array} \right)
= T^{-1}
\left( \begin{array}{c : c}
\tilde{L} & 0 \\
\hdashline
\tilde{L}_Q & \tilde{Q}
\end{array} \right)
T
$,

where $L, \tilde{L} \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$,
$L_Q\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $\tilde{L}_Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, and
$Q, \tilde{Q} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.

Comment: Isnt this the schur decomposition

Comment: @Shogun Thanks for the comment! Now I'll just look for block matrix version.